# What does setApprovalForAll do when minting an NFT directly from contracts on Etherscan?

Tags: contract-invocation, etherscan, nft

When there is a contract :

It says

Approve

Get access by card

Or if it says ————-

Whitelist address

Set approval

Claim free mint

Mint _____

And I’m trying to just mint the project

In both of these cases - the top on would I just set approval, then wait for the mint to be available

And in the bottom example if it says set approval then what would u do next if your goal is to mint or get acces to mint

Here’s a picture of ethereans -

[image]

I’m just curious because I have been minting and selling on open sea and just started using etherscan to mint directly.

I’m looking to know for future projects

Comment: Have you figured out what set for approval for all do?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to mint, then `setApprovalForAll` is not needed. You would instead simple call the `mint` function. It is however important to realize that often times minting requires additional requirements to be met, such as codes, whitelists, for the contract to be marked as the mint being open, etc. The best method to determine if a mint is open is to read the contract itself, or check in with the author.

`setApprovalForAll` is an important (and dangerous!) transaction for decentralized marketplaces to function. The approval you are granting is for the delegated contract to be able to approve transfers for a token. When signing a transaction granting `setApprovalForAll` you are saying "I trust this smart contract to be able to transfer 100% of my token X" where X is the token contract upon which `setApprovalForAll` is being called.

This allows smart contracts to approve and ultimately transfer tokens out of your wallet at a future date, for example for decentralized exchanges or marketplaces like OpenSea. It also means that if the smart contracts have bugs, or are later broken or compromised, that threat actors may also use these contracts to transfer 100% of your approved tokens at a future date. This is where tools like Etherscan or https://revoke.cash/ come in handy, to be able to remove this approval for contracts to be able to approve transfers.

Ultimately you are trusting that the smart contract that you approving is written correctly and is bug free so that it will only transfer tokens that you expect.